# Integer overflow gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7-beta3

While messing around with Swift, I noticed that when the 64 bit integer overflows, I get the following error:

> file:///Users/user/Documents/playground/MyPlayground.playground/: error: Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

```
func fibonacci(which: Int) -> (fibOf: Int, isEqualTo: Int) {
    var i = 1, j = 1

    for var k = 2; k < which; k += 1 {
        let tmp = i + j // this line is highlighted when error occurs
        j = i
        i = tmp
    }

    return (which, i)
}

print (fibonacci(92))
print (fibonacci(93)) // this triggers an error
```

The first call, i.e. with 92 as argument, will run fine. When supplying the 93 value however, I get the irrelevant EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. Is this a bug or what? Normally I'd expect it to overflow.

Comment: I found this by googling "Swift integer overflow": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is expected behaviour. If you want to overflow, you need to use [overflow operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID37).

- Overflow addition (`&+`)
- Overflow subtraction (`&-`)
- Overflow multiplication (`&*`)

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Unintuitive error message though. Thanks