# When matrix powering, have debugging error code = EXC_I386_INVOP

Tags: swift, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

when i raised the power of matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] to 1000,

occur `code=EXC_I386_INVOP` error.

Is it possible that this error is caused by a large Int?

Comment: The entries of the result are integers with approx 1200 decimal digits – so yes, the integer arithmetic does overflow. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417588/integer-overflow-gives-exc-bad-instruction-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR It works!! Thank you for your helping!!

Comment: You could use a `BigInt` library like [this one](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt).